# How to get rid of repeating variable in str.format?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have a string template which i use to format few times during code execution with only one unique varible `some_var`:

```
message_tmpl = '{}. Path  {} cannot be extracted'
some_var = '123'
condition = True # or False...
if condition:
    message = message_tmpl.format('True message', some_var)
else:
    message = message_tmpl.format('False Message', some_var)
```

How i can improve that flow to avoid passing of `some_var` each time?

I've tried to run code snippet below without success:

```
message_tmpl = '{msg}. Path  {some_var} cannot be extracted'.format(some_var=some_var)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an additional pair of braces around `{msg}`, like this:

```
>>> some_var = '123'
>>> message_tmpl = '{{msg}}. Path  {some_var} cannot be extracted'.format(some_var=some_var)
>>> message_tmpl.format(msg='a message')
'a message. Path  123 cannot be extracted'
```

In general, nesting braces is what you need if your template needs to be filled gradually. A bit more demo:

```
>>> template = '{} {{}} {{{{}}}}'
>>> template.format('foo')
'foo {} {{}}'
>>> template.format('foo').format('bar')
'foo bar {}'
>>> template.format('foo').format('bar').format('baz')
'foo bar baz'
```

Answer (score 2):

That could be done by specific formatting of template: passing `'{}'` for first formatting in template:

```
message_tmpl = '{}. Path  {} cannot be extracted'.format('{}', some_var)
```

Or

```
message_tmpl = '{msg}. Path  {some_var} cannot be extracted'.format(msg='{}', some_var=some_var)
```

After creating template in such way passing of `some_var` should  be removed from next formatting and only `msg` passed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use old-style formatting with the new-style:

```
message_tmpl = '{msg}. Path %(some_var)s cannot be extracted' % {'some_var': some_var}
```